# How to build Test APK for Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-instrumentation, firebase-test-lab, gui-testing

Firebase Test Lab asks to upload two APKs:

1. App APK
2. Test APK

How to build test APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:
`./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest`

The Test APK will be built in:
`app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/<flavor>/debug/app-<flavor>-debug-androidTest.apk`